# In the GAN objective function, why do we first do we first find the D(x) that maximizes the objective function and then maximise wrt the generator?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-function, gan, generative-models, objective-function

The GAN objective function is optimised like this: argmin(argmax(L(G,D))) where the argmax finds the D (Discriminator) that maximises L(G,D). Why is it not the other way around, i.e. argmax(argmin(L(G,D))) where argmin minimises L(G,D) with respect to G and argmax does the same but with D?
Or would these two approaches yield the same result?